# Both Copy and Remove Node with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have a seemingly unique situation in which I want to use DOMDocument to find a node on page, store it's value into variable (working), then remove it from the output. I am not able to figure out how to remove the node from the DOMDocument output and still save it's value first.

I am able to either remove the node completely first, which means nothing is stored in the variable, or I receive a 'Not Found Error' when trying to remove the node.

There is only one node (`<h6>`) on the page that needs to be removed. The code I have so far (with not found error) is below.

```
// Strip Everything Before and After Header Tags
$domdoc = new DOMDocument;
$docnew = new DOMDocument;

// Disable errors for <article> tag
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domdoc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($file));
libxml_clear_errors();

$body = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

foreach ($body->childNodes as $child){
    $docnew->appendChild($docnew->importNode($child, true));
}

// Get the Page Title
$ppretitle = $docnew->getElementsByTagName('h6')->item(0);
$pagetitle = $ppretitle->nodeValue;

// Remove Same Element From Output
$trunctitl = $docnew->removeChild($ppretitle);

// Save Cleaned Output In Var
$pagecontent = $docnew->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Can we see a sample HTML that can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `h6` element might not be a direct child node of the `body` element: try `$ppretitle->parentNode->removeChild($ppretitle)` instead of `$trunctitl = $docnew->removeChild($ppretitle);`